# Looping over large CSV file

Tags: python-3.x, python-itertools

I am trying to loop over a large CSV file, writing all the lines but the variable names to a new file, while playing around with efficient ways of doing so. I'm using islice from itertools. Does anyone have any tips for a more efficient way than my code below?

```
from itertools import islice
var = len(csv)

with open("csv_file1.csv") as file1, open("trial1.csv", 'w') as file2:
    head1 = list(islice(file1, var))[0].split(",")
    while (var > 1): 
        for line in head1:
            file2.write(str(head1))
            file2.write("\n")
            var = var - 1
            print(var)
file2.close()
```

Comment: What do you mean by variable names in the csv file, do you mean the 1st line(the header)? If not can you show us part of the csv that you are working with.

Comment: Also, Python has csv module, which can abstract CSV-file syntax details better.

Answer (score 2):

- Use `csv` module, as suggested in comments
- Wrap your incoming file into a generator, which is a good practice for dealing with any stream, including a csv file

```
def read_csv(filename):
    with open(filename) as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        for row in reader:
            yield row
```

After that `read_csv("csv_file1.csv")` gives you a generator that you can use either in for-loop or apply map/filter functions to it, depending on the logic of row transformation.